# How can I sort a list using a method that uses the list's item as a parameter?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

Let's say that I have the following list and method:

```
List<myObject> myList = (some function that prepopulates myList);
```

I would like to sort `myList` in descending order using a method that I created:

```
int sortByThisValue(myObject obj)
{
    int someInteger;
    // Operations on obj that generates a value for someInteger
    ...
    return someInteger;
}
```

The first solution that comes to mind is to create a sorted Dictionary and then extract the values as a list.  However, this fails when two objects generate the same `someInteger` because a dictionary must have a unique set of keys.  What is the best way sort this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ makes this easy:

```
// Method group conversion
List<myObject> sorted = myList.OrderByDescending(SortByThisValue).ToList();

// Lambda expression
List<myObject> sorted = myList.OrderByDescending(x => SortByThisValue(x))
                              .ToList();
```

Note that this does *not* sort the list in-place; it creates a new list. If you don't need to actually create a new list, just remove the `ToList` call at the end, e.g.

```
foreach (MyObject item in myList.OrderByDescending(x => SortByThisValue(x))
{
    // Do something
}
```

It's well worth looking into LINQ - it makes all kinds of data querying *really* simple.

If you absolutely need to sort in-place, you could use:

```
myList.Sort((x, y) => SortByThisValue(y).CompareTo(SortByThisValue(x)));
```

(Note the use of `y` followed by `x` here - that's what's reversing the "natural" ordering so that you get the values in descending order.)

It's uglier than the LINQ version though, IMO.

Comment: Jon, has Google ever asked you how you were able to spend so much time on Stack Overflow while working for them? :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `LINQ`?

```
myList = myList.OrderByDescending(p=>p.someInteger).ToList();
```

or Asecending

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(p=>p.someInteger).ToList();
```

Alternatively, if you want to do manual sorting, you can implement `IComparer` interface.  This may be required if the sorting is complex and not easily achieved using `LINQ`.

```
class MyListSorter : IComparer<myObject>
{
    public int Compare(myObject x, myObject y)
    {
        if (x.Num < y.Num) return 1;
        if (x.Num > y.Num) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}

myList.Sort(new MyListSorter());
```

Comment: And if you don't want to use LINQ, `myList.Sort((x, y) => { return x.someValue.CompareTo(y.someValue); });`